# .NET NotifyIcon displays a toast notification twice in Windows 10

Tags: c#, .net, windows-10, toast, notifyicon

I use the .NET Framework System.Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon class to display a tray icon and tray notifications. When I call ShowBalloonTip on its instance, first the previously displayed notification displays again, then it hides, and only after a while does the expected one is displayed. It seems that historical notifications are displayed first unless I remove them manually from the notification center.

What can I do programmatically to prevent showing the historical notifications again?

Here's how I initialize the notify icon:

```
notifyIcon.Icon = Properties.Resources.tray_icon;
notifyIcon.Visible = true;

notifyIcon.BalloonTipTitle = Language.TrayMessageTitle;
```

Here's how I show the toast:

```
notifyIcon.BalloonTipIcon = icon;
notifyIcon.BalloonTipText = message;
notifyIcon.ShowBalloonTip(0);
```

- The icon is either ToolTipIcon.Error or ToolTipIcon.Info, and I don't show a toast with the same icon twice, so they always toggle. But this does not seem to matter.
- The timeout param is 0, because it's not used since Windows Vista.
- The toast is displayed as a result of an application state change, not as a result of a user action like clicking.

Comment: It seems that when I dispose the notifyIcon instance on the BalloonTipClosed event and then recreate it, the problem does not occur, and only the latest toast is displayed. However, doing so causes the tray icon to blink. Is there a less bad solution? :)

Comment: why do you even dispose of the notifyIcon , you can create one Form wide using VS toolbox like any other control

Comment: Could you please tell me a few more words what you mean exactly?

Comment: which project do you have (winForm, WPF, UWP , other?)

Comment: This is a WPF project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I decided to stick with disposing the notify icon instance and recreating it every time I display a toast notification. I don't think it's fine, but I couldn't find a better solution.

I also dispose the notify icon on application shutdown to clean the notification center from previously displayed notifications. Otherwise, the last one displays first when another application displays a toast.